# Why isn't my Javascript working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am new to coding and I need to use Javascript in my code. I have a checkbox within an HTML table (*below*).

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="check1"/> 
<label th:text="${item.contents}">&nbsp;</label>
</td>
```

I am trying to use Javascript to alert me when I have checked the box with the code below.

```
<script>

$('#check1').click(function() {
    if($(this).not(':checked'))
        alert('unchecked');
    else
        alert('checked');
});

</script>
```

Why isn't it working? I don't get an error, but nothing happens either. 
Thank you.

Comment: your html markup is invalid to start with specifically the label element

Comment: `<label th:text="${item.contents}">&nbsp;</label>` is not standard HTML. I'm not sure it's valid anywhere. You aren't seeing any error messages [in your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log)

Comment: Are you including jQuery? I have to imagine that you are getting errors.

Comment: Where is your `<script>` located? If it is before the element, then your code is called before the element exists, you need to be using a ready event like onload or `jQuery.ready`

Comment: Please read [ask], specifically the part about writing a title that reflects the contents of the post. Your current title is quite vague.

Comment: I'm not familiar with th:text but ${item.context} could be groovy/grails gsp logic.

Comment: @j08691 That fiddle always displays "unchecked".

Comment: FYI, it needs to be `.is()` not `.not()`, `not()` removes elements that match the selector, while `is()` is the one that does a test

Comment: [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) removes elements from the collection. You should be using [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check if it has been checked.

Comment: @MikeC good catch.  jQuery object are always truthy

Comment: @ScottMarcus I just meant that it was throwing the alert, but you're right, it's not functioning properly

Comment: @j08691 Well, there is an `alert` in both of the `if` branches, so why wouldn't you get an `alert()`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus For example, if he wasn't loading jQuery or was running the code before the DOM was ready

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first, you have some syntax that is not HTML here:

```
 <label **th:text="${item.contents}"**>
```

And, if that non-HTML code is incorrect, that could be enough for the page to stop processing. You say you don't get an error, but do you mean that you've checked your developer tools console window and don't see an error there?

As for the checkbox, neither the table cell, nor the label are related to your goal.

Next, JQuery is a great thing, but it sometimes makes things that are already easy, harder. Your code is actually EXCLUDING any checked elements from the wrapped set that will be examined because you are using `not()`.

Here is a solution that doesn't rely on JQuery:

```js
var chk = document.getElementById("check1");

chk.addEventListener("click", function(){

  // The following is not part of your question, but is
  // added just for completeness:

  // Because the alert() is modal, it will block the UI
  // from updating and it will most likely appear before
  // the UI updates the checkbox to the latest appearance.
  // To solve this, we add a short delay before making the
  // alert using a timer and we need to store the checked
  // status of the checkbox outside of the timer's callback
  // function.
  var on = this.checked;
  setTimeout(function(){

     var message = "checked";
     if(!on){
       message = "un" + message;
     }
     alert(message);

  }, 50);

});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's normally very wise to listen to click events on things like checkboxes and radio buttons. From what I understand they may be triggered before the value of the input is updated, depending on where you catch the event in the dom.

I'm not sure what the html syntax is on your label, the `th:text` part, but it seems to be some sort of templating syntax and also may be unrelated. To help simplify the problem also I will give you an example without using jQuery, jQuery often adds unnecessary complexity to simple problems.

A properly working example of your code using vanilla javascript (without jquery) would be,

```
document.getElementById("check1").addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var checked = this.checked;
    if(checked) { alert("Checked"); }
    else { alert("Unchecked"); }
});
```

And with jquery, a working example is:

```
$("#check1").on("change", function(e) {
    var checked = this.checked;
    if(checked) { alert("Checked"); }
    else { alert("Unchecked"); }
});
```

Comment: Event handlers stored as DOM object properties should be avoided in favor of the W3C DOM Event handling standard of `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I believe you're right, I updated my answer to reflect your comment.